# How can we take dielectric medium kept between the capacitor plates as capacitors in series and solve for effective capacitance?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, capacitance

My book says that the charge induced on the dielectric slab kept between the parallel plates is given $Qp=Q(1-1/K)$ where $K$ is the dielectric constant and $Q$ is the charge on the capacitor.

I have seen that in some books equivalent capacitance of capacitors with dielectric in the middle partially filled is found by taking 2 capacitors in series combination. But I thought that to take 2 capacitors in series, they must have same magnitude of charges. But it doesn't seem like the dielectric surface has the same charge as that of the capacitors.

Am I wrong or is the condition for series not quite straightforward as I assumed?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a capacitor with parallel plates, if you put a very thin conducting plate somewhere in between , it does not change the C, and you can consider it as two capacitors in a row. Now insert the dielectricum in one of them.